# How to change git bash to align left

Tags: git, git-bash

In my version the code is aligned to the right.
I want it to be aligned to the left,
I'm using Windows 10 in Hebrew (rtl language), and i didn't find it in the settings section. How do I change it?

Comment: Windows cmd? Does `chcp 65001` do the trick?

Comment: unfortunately no..

Comment: The question is not related to Git in any way. And btw, there is no such thing as "git-bash". It's official name is ["Git for Windows"](https://gitforwindows.org) and the Bash it provides is just a Bash that runs on Windows, nothing else. Any other shell that run on Windows (including the old Windows Command Prompt and the new Windows Power Shell) is as good as Bash to run Git command lines in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Bidi=0` in your `~/.minttyrc` file.

See https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html#CONFIGURATION